# Most efficient way to break python list into sublists via key while preserving the order

Tags: python, list

First time poster here. If I have a list that contains sublists with different information, and I want to group all sublists with the same key value into a new sublist (e.g. unique-ify a list based on the key values), what is the most efficient way to do this?

Example:

```
A = [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [2,1,3], [8,9,6], [3,7,9], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]
```

And I want to group all sublists that have the same item in the '0' index into one new sublist, preferably preserving the original order:

```
B = [ [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [1,2,4]], [[2,1,3],[2,3,8]], [[8,9,6]], [[3,7,9]] ]
```

I have solved this problem many times, but I would like to see if there is a more efficient way to do this. Yes, I could be using the numpy package for this reason, but I'm interested in the list solution.

Typically, I would first unique-ify the item in the first index in each sublist (using the set method if I don't worry about efficiency or order), then loop over the entire list, combining sublists into a new sublist:

```
def getUniqueList(list):
    seen = []
    for e in list:
        if e not in seen:
        seen.append(e)
    return seen

def uniquify(list):
    # Get all items from the first column
    new_list = [item[0] for item in list]
    return getUniqueList(new_list)

def rearrangeList(A, A_0):
    B = []
    for i in range(len(A_0)):
        B.append([])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        index = A_0.index(A[i][0])
        B[index].append(A[i])
    return B

A = [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [2,1,3], [8,9,6], [3,7,9], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]
A_0 = uniquify(A) # Contains all unique keys in index 0 of list A
B = rearrangeList(A, A_0)
print(B)
```

This *should* (I didn't test this, but this is how I would code it) result in:

> B = [ [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [1,2,4]], [[2,1,3],[2,3,8]], [[8,9,6]], [[3,7,9]] ]

I wanted to know if 1) there was a better way of doing this in terms of efficiency, and 2) is there a way to do this in less steps (not necessarily efficiently, just curious). Hopefully this question is posed well, but let me know if it needs editing!

Comment: The best people to suggest improvements to working code will be using http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: Preserving the order of the groups makes this question different from the simple grouping problem. Note that adding a `sorted` to the resulting list doesn't create the sorting as requested in the question.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, thanks, I will try that next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want a grouping operation. Use a dictionary to group by keys, use OrderedDict to perserve order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> groups = OrderedDict()
>>> A = [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [2,1,3], [8,9,6], [3,7,9], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]
>>> key = lambda l: l[0]
>>> for sub in A:
...   groups.setdefault(key(sub),[]).append(sub)
... 
>>> groups
OrderedDict([(1, [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 7], [1, 2, 4]]), (2, [[2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]]), (8, [[8, 9, 6]]), (3, [[3, 7, 9]])])
>>> B = list(groups.values())
>>> B
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 7], [1, 2, 4]], [[2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]], [[8, 9, 6]], [[3, 7, 9]]]
```

Comment: why not `B = list(groups.values())` ??

Comment: @Copperfield oh I was just being stupid.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, this helped immensely, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for preserving the order of the original list is interesting.

Assuming that your list is `A` and you want the result in `B`, the following code constructs the list as it consumes the input, hence the original order of the list are preserved:

```
from collections import defaultdict
B=[]
reduce(lambda a,n: a[n[0]].append(n) or a,A,defaultdict(lambda: B.append([]) or B[-1]))
```

or the following simpler code creates the list inside defaultdict and then copies over, but the order of the original list is lost:

```
from collections import defaultdict
B=reduce(lambda a,n: a[n[0]].append(n) or a,A,defaultdict(list)).values()
```

Note that the sublists will be in the order they appear originally.

Answer (score -1):

An old school (but good and simple) approach:

```
A = [[1,2,3], [1,3,7], [2,1,3], [8,9,6], [3,7,9], [2,3,8], [1,2,4]]
A = sorted(A, key=lambda x: x[0]) #sort just by the first index to preserve order
B = [[A[0]]]

for list in A[1:]:              # add to the last list or create new one
    if B[-1][-1][0]==list[0]:   #
        B[-1].append(list)      #
    else:                       #
        B.append([list])        #

B
#output: 
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 7], [1, 2, 4]], [[2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 8]], [[3, 7, 9]], [[8, 9, 6]]]
```